# Changing Font in autogenerated HTML e-mail message

Tags: html, email

I need to send a lot of numbers over so want to change the font to Courier.

HGow do I do this? My constructs are...

```
$message = "Contact      : ".$_SESSION["Contact"]."\n\r".

...

$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

When I try simple tests like bold on/off or spans suggested elsewhere they just appear as the text and are transmitted and appear identically in Outlook and my iPhone. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using php, so the next syntax should work. Just add the next headers to what you already have or replace the one you have with similar content:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
```

And change your text to something like this:

```
$message = "Contact      : "<span style="font-face:courier;">.$_SESSION["Contact"]<span>."\n\r".
```

I'm assuming that line is the one with the numbers you want to format. But of course you can modify any line in your message

Bye